# optimization of sum of multi variable functions

Tags: algorithm, math

Imagine that I'm a bakery trying to maximize the number of pies I can produce with my limited quantities of ingredients.

Each of the following pie recipes `A, B, C, and D` produce exactly 1 pie:

```
A = i + j + k
B = t + z
C = 2z
D = 2j + 2k
```

*The recipes always have linear form, like above.

I have the following ingredients:

```
4 of i
5 of z
4 of j
2 of k
1 of t
```

I want an algorithm to maximize my pie production given my limited amount of ingredients.

The optimal solution of these example inputs would yield me the following quantities of pies:

```
2 x A
1 x B
2 x C
0 x D
= a total of 5 pies
```

I can solve this easily enough by taking the maximal producer of all combinations, but the number 
of combos becomes prohibitive as the quantities of ingredients increases. I feel like there must 
be generalizations of this type of optimization problem, I just don't know where to start.

While I can only bake whole pies, I would be still be interested in seeing a method which may produce non integer results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. I'll show the usage on the example, but it can of course be generalized to any data.

Denote your pies as your variables (x1 = A, x2 = B, ...) and the LP problem will be as follows:

```
maximize x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
s.t. x1 <= 4  (needed i's)
     x1 + 2x4 <= 4 (needed j's)
     x1 + 2x4 <= 2 (needed k's)
     x2 <= 1 (needed t's)
     x2 + 2x3 <= 5 (needed z's)
and x1,x2,x3,x4 >= 0
```

The fractional solution to this problem is solveable polynomially, but the integer linear programming is NP-Complete.

The problem is indeed [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), because given an [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem, you can reduce the problem to "maximize the number of pies" using the same approach, where each constraint is an ingredient in the pie and the variables are the number of pies.

For the integers problem - there are a lot of approximation techniques in the literature for the problem if you can do with "close up to a certain bound", (for example [local ratio technique](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~reuven/PDF/survay04.pdf) or [primal-dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28optimization%29) are often used) or if you need an exact solution - exponential solution is probably your best shot. (Unless of course, [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem))

Comment: BTW rounding the fractional solution is often a good solution to the integer problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since all your functions are linear, it sounds like you're looking for either [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (if continuous values are acceptable) or [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (if you require your variables to be integers).

Linear programming is a standard technique, and is efficiently solvable.  A traditional algorithm for doing this is the [simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

Integer programming is intractable in general, because adding integral constraints allows it to describe intractable combinatorial problems.  There seems to be a large number of approximation techniques (for example, you might try just using regular linear programming to see what that gets you), but of course they depend on the specific nature of your problem.